# Shell script tokenizer

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm writing a script that queries my JBoss server for some database related data. The thing that is returned after the query looks like this:

```
ConnectionCount=7
ConnectionCreatedCount=98
MaxConnectionsInUseCount=10
ConnectionDestroyedCount=91
AvailableConnectionCount=10
InUseConnectionCount=0
MaxSize=10
```

I would like to tokenize this data so the numbers on the right hand side are stored in a variable in the format `7,98,10,91,10,0,10`. I tried to use `IFS` with the equals sign, but that still keeps the parameter names (only the equals signs are eliminated).

Comment: what do you want to do with that array then?

Comment: print it out like a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your input data into file `d.txt`. The one-liner below extracts the numbers, comma-delimits them and assigns all that to variable `TAB` (tested with Korn shell):

```
$ TAB=$(awk -F= '{print $2}' d.txt | xargs echo | sed 's/ /,/g')
$ echo $TAB
7,98,10,91,10,0,10
```

Comment: +1 I particullary like the way you pass from `7\n98\n...10` to `7,98,...10`

Comment: This doesn't put the result in array!?

Comment: @sudo_O I asked what was the purpose of "storing the numbers in an array", see comments under the question, and the answer was "print it out like a table". Therefore I concluded that an array is not really needed, and gave a direct solution, which, apparently, satisfied Tamás, as he accepted the answer. BTW, did you downvote my answer?

Comment: @piokuc ah yes, I have edited the question to reflect this. The `| xrags echo | sed ..` is quite strange, I would have done `awk -F'=' '{printf "%s%s",sep,$2;sep=","}END{print ""}' file`. Nope.

Comment: @sudo_O For me the trick with xargs is OK, results in a simpler code. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Or just use cut/tr:

```
 F=($(cut -d'=' -f2 input | tr '\n' ' '))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with one sed command too:

```
sed -n 's/^.*=\(.*\)/\1,/;H;${g;s/\n//g;s/,$//;p;}' file
7,98,10,91,10,0,10
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `cut` without any pipes :

```
arr=( $(cut -d'=' -f2 file) )
```

### Outut

```
printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
7
98
10
91
10
0
10
```